# Wordpress slideshow not working

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, slideshow

I'm working with the Cherry WP template, and can't get the slideshow to load on any pages. I've saved an image under Slides and triple checked all the settings under the Slider. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

The website URL is: http://www.croydontattooconvention.com/

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Is there some kind of shortcode you need to include on the page?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, it simply has an 'on/off' switch within the theme's settings.

Comment: Is the slideshow using a plugin, or is it part of the Cherry template? These things are usually an additional plugin.

Comment: It's within the template, under Cherry Options > Slider Settings. Double checked the plugins, but there is nothing for a slider.

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with this theme...wish I could help more.

Comment: The theme creators are dealing with the problem now, but that doesn't help to understand what was wrong in the first place. Ah well, thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

In the wordpress dashboard go to any of your pages click on Visual, you wil get insert a cherry code option. In that under basic tab you will find carousel try with that..